# How to change an image color in flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, bitmap

I have a doubt in flex 3.

I'm trying to change an image color in flex 3, but I can't get it still. I think have to change the image color by using pixels, but I don't know how to do it.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you want to change one specific color in your image or do you want to change the overall color (e.g. adding more blue in your image)?

Comment: I need to change overall color but not the same color to all pixels. For example i have a mobile image. Here i want to change the color of panel,buttons,screen,navigators separately by using color picker. Will u help me for this????

Comment: As said by Timofei Davydik, you should look into the usage of colorTransform on your images. For each seperate component, you will need another colortransform.

Comment: Yeah ok but how can i split the image into separate parts???

Comment: It is possible, but why would you want to do that? Don't you have different images for your buttons/panels/...

Comment: No i have only one mobile image. From that i have to split the parts and have to change the color of individual parts. I tried with colortransform() method but the whole image background is getting changed. For example if i put white color means the whole image is changed to white color. The image is completely gone.

Comment: And how will you create an app with only one image? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm not going to create a big application. Just i want to change an image color that's it. By using color picker i have to change the mobile image color part by part.

Comment: I don't see the point in doing that. Why would you have buttons and panels if yoy can't do anything with them? (because if you only have one image, you can't add any functionality). So again, why do you really want to use only one image?

Comment: Ok now i'm using nearly 4 images to change the Mobile color. But when i was using color transform method it dint change the image background color . That image contains some letters and shadows and icons but if i change that image backgroundcolor the total image part has been changed. what to do?

Comment: Changing only the backgroundcolor without the letters is practically impossible. Create a custom component with the image (no letters) and a label in front of your image. If you go over your component then, you can change the backgroundcolor without change the text-color.

Comment: can u post any sample code to change the image color???

Comment: That is what the colortransform does. there is no other way (at least not preprogrammed) to change an image's color. The multiplier of an colortransform multiplies the chosen channel of the original image by a given number. the offset adds a value to every chosen value (e.g. redOffset adds to red etc..) that's all I can say.

Answer (score 1):

Read about [Bitmap](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Bitmap.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6), [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6) and [ColorTransform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html). [Here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Changing_the_color_of_solid_colored_images-211.html)'s an example of using ColorTransform class. Hope, this will help you.

Comment: If i change the image color by using color transform method means the total image has been changed. i cant able to change the backgroundcolor alone.